# split DB table across two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm needing to take a table I have `origArticleTable` that contains `Title,date1, date2,author, articleText, hasVideo, hasImage, ArticleID` and split it into two tables.  I need two tables because I'm having to include data from other sources that do not contain all the same content.  for example another source would have a table containing `title, itemDescription, date1, urlLink, comments, uniqueID`.

Basically I'm moving my `origArticleTable` into a "composite" table and a meta table or support table, and to do that the question I have is "when I insert into the `CompositeTable`, can I nest, or something, another insert to populate `ArticleMeta` with the identity generated by insert to `CompositeTable`"

I'll break them down here:

```
compositeTable
    ID (auto-incrementing identity column)
    Title
    date1
    TextContent


ArticleMeta
    compositeID
    ArticleID
    hasVideo
    hasImage
    author
    date2
```

What I am unsure of how to do is insert data from my current table into these two tables.  I can't put data into the `ArticleMeta` without there already being a corresponding entry in the `CompositeTable`.  I understand that I would insert an item into the `CompositeTable` and using the `ID` insert the remaining info into the `ArticleMeta`.

I have tried to design an `insert-select` statement using joins to combine the `origArticleTable` and `CompositeTable` involving an insert into the `CompositeTable` but have been unsuccessful in building anything that even looks like it will work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If there is anything that needs a better explanation or anything let me know.

Edit ----
here's the `insert-select` mess that I tried to work with.  It's changed since I started.

```
insert into ArticleMeta (compositeID, ArticleID, hasVideo, hasImage, author, date2)
    select id from (insert into CompositeTable (Title, date1, textContent)
                        select Title, date1, articleText 
                            from origArticleTable)
    join
    select ArticleID, hasVideo, hasImage, author, date2
        from origArticleTable
```

Comment: Some particular reason you can't just mark some columns as NULLABLE?

Comment: Can you edit-post your attempted insert-select and why it didn't work?

Comment: @TabAlleman  I'll add that right away.

Comment: @Bill  I'm wanting to keep the tables as clean as possible, and with at the moment there being about 9 other sources whose tables contain mostly different information (aside from title, a specific date, and the main text), I figured this might be the best approach

Comment: I have tried various permutations of the attempted `insert-select` and couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If title is a unique key in the original table, then do something like this.  If the unique key from the original table will not be in the new table, then add it temporarily and then drop it after.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Title varchar(50), NewID int)
INSERT INTO compositeTable (Title, date1, TextContent)
OUTPUT inserted.Title, Inserted.ID INTO @T1
SELECT compositeTable (Title, date1, TextContent)
FROM origArticleTable 


insert into ArticleMeta (compositeID, ArticleID, hasVideo, hasImage, author, date2)
SELECT T1.ID, o.compositeID, o.ArticleID, o.hasVideo, o.hasImage, o.author, o.date2
FROM @T1 T1 
INNER JOIN origArticleTable o ON T1.Title = o.Title
```